# How can I run a Class with main() when doing mvn clean install

Tags: plugins, maven, build, exec

I want to execute a class's main method (for this I found [this Exec Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html)), what I want to do is to execute this plugin automatically when building the project.
I don't need to `mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable="java"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any plugin can be added to `<build>/<plugins>` section and bound to particular phase to execute automatically. In fact Exec Plugin page has an [example](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Here is a [guide to configuring](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html) plugins with more examples. Search for word `phase`.

Comment: my problem now is that the class I want to run doesn't see the dependencies my project has ..

Comment: Pls provide pom.xml that does not work (add to your question)

Comment: classpathScope helped me. THanks.